# what is the best way to start a script in boot time on linux

Tags: linux, boot, systemd

I want to start a script I have on when the system start and looking for the best way, my way is:

- vi /etc/systemd/system/myscript.service

  ```
  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/myscript
  CPUSchedulingPolicy=rr
  CPUSchedulingPrioty=27
  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target graphical.target
  ```
- `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl enable myscript; systemctl start rmyscript`

it's working good but just wondered if there another and better way.

Comment: In the systemd based environment, service is the best option to start your scritp/programs. Note you can set other parameters on when to start your service and add dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, but you will need root privileges for any the following. To get root, open a terminal and run the command:

```
sudo su
```

and the command prompt will change to '#' indicating that the terminal session has root privileges.

**Alternative #1. Add an initscript**

Create a new script in `/etc/init.d/myscript`:

```
vi /etc/init.d/myscript
```

(Obviously it doesn't have to be called "myscript".) In this script, do whatever you want to do. Perhaps just run the script you mentioned:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/my/script.sh
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/myscript
```

Configure the init system to run this script at startup:

```
update-rc.d myscript defaults
```

**Alternative #2. Add commands to /etc/rc.local**

```
vi /etc/rc.local
```

with content like the following:

```bash
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
/path/to/my/script.sh || exit 1   # Added by me
exit 0
```

**Alternative #3. Add an Upstart job**

Create `/etc/init/myjob.conf`:

```
vi /etc/init/myjob.conf
```

with the following content:

```
description "my job"
start on startup
task
exec /path/to/my/script.sh
```

BTW:

You don't need to be root if you can edit your crontab `(crontab -e)` and create an entry like this:

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

This way, you can run it as a regular user. @reboot just means it's run when the computer starts up (not necessarily just when it's rebooted).

Comment: Dint like the answer