# Bash script to run automatically after server restart

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have a script, it restarts tomcat in 2 minutes,, I would like that 
 this script  was started constantly after server restart, I will be grateful if someone shows how to do it?

```html
#! /bin/bash
sleep 120
systemctl restart tomcat
```

Comment: `bvin was started constantly` ? Could you please explain

Comment: @DigvijayS I corrected)

Comment: Call script in `.profile` or `.bashrc`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861280/what-is-the-best-way-to-start-a-script-in-boot-time-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

Read [archwiki about systemd/Timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) or maybe [original freedesktop documentation about systemd.timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html).

Create a file `my_super_tomcat_restarter.timer` in `/etc/systemd/system/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Superbly restart my tomcat service every 120 seconds!

[Timer]
OnBootSec=120sec
OnUnitActiveSec=120sec

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Create a file `my_super_tomcat_restarter.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/` with the content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Superbly restart tomcat service!

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart tomcat
```

Execute from your terminal as `root`:

```
systemctl enable my_super_tomcat_restarter.timer
```

The timer should fire in 120 seconds and execute `my_super_tomcat_restarter.service` which in turn will restart your tomcat service.

Answer (score 0):

either add it in `init.d` or `systemd` based on your Linux distribution of yours. in both cases you have to be root to add your script.